# How can I observe exchange rates?

Tags: foreign-exchange, travel

I need a lot of Euros because I frequently travel to European countries. Therefore, I always have an amount of Euros at home and from time to time I exchange a large amount of Euro. To save some money, I try to observe the exchange rate and try to get a favorable one. Doing this manually is a little bit tedious and therefore I'm looking for a tool that does this for me. The tool should be able to observe a specific exchange rate and inform me via email if a certain rate is achieved or if trend/forecast show that a minimum is reached.

Is there any tool like this available? I'm interested in a generic solution, but for now a tool for CHF - EUR and CHF - USD would also be okay.

Comment: https://www.google.com/finance?q=CHFUSD&ei=k_5aUeinH4GO0QH_0gE

Comment: Forecasting exchange rates is very hard. Exchange rates are a volatile and very complex phenomenon. Historical series can be obtained via e.g. http://finance.yahoo.com/

Comment: If you know a scripting language à la Python or Perl, you can easily knit such a tool by yourself. Use the script to extract the current exchange rate and to send you a notification whenever the rate crosses a certain threshold.

Comment: If you travel to Europe a lot then when bother exchanging your Euros at all? I'd imagine any profit you make could be lost whilst converting constantly between the currencies.

Comment: @Andrew, I think s/he means that s/he buys a lot of Euros every so often, then gradually uses them up before buying some more.

Comment: @Vicky That is possible, although it would be good to edit the question in order to make it clearer. "from time to time I exchange a large amount of Euro" to me sounds like it is about exchanging Euros into another currency.

Answer (score 3):

While the following is not automated as requested, it is one-click-easy, and present s the desired result in clear and readable form for manual transcription, or for "programmatic action" [tm] depending on your skill set./

Some sites allow you to  easily access pages that clearly display the rates of your choice.
One such is [www.xe.com](http://www.xe.com), but there are many others.

Here is XE's CHF -> EUR page (https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=CHF&To=EUR)

- so you can see how this could be easily manipulated "programmatically".

---

[**OANDA - Free unlimited rates by email**](http://www.oanda.com/rates/currency-data/e-mail/)

What's the catch? - rates are delayed by one day.
Useful to observe trends. Not so good for sudden blips.

**Also current data at various costs .**

---

Many companies WILL provide you with a live rate feed but, sadly but not surprisingly, tend to want $ in return.

Possibly useful:

[XE](http://www.xe.com)

[XE currency data feed - real $s](http://www.xe.com/datafeed/?WT.mc_id=XDF-TL-XUCO-XIN-XX-currencyconverter_convert_V03-130301)

[XE EUR -> USD page](http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=USD)

[Currency Online - twitter feeds available](http://www.currencyonline.com/?gclid=CJXWqNPVrLYCFQZcpQodSgcAFg)

[FX Street - live rates](http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/currency-rates/)